# Migração de banco de dados de um servidor para outro

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho um E-Commerce que desenvolvi através do Wordpress, todo o BD dele estava no meu antigo servidor, com a URL http://www.felipestoker.com/teste
Agora, já finalizado, tenho que exportar tudo para http://www.teste.com.br

Já exportei os arquivos, instalei o Banco de dados no novo servidor, porém estou tendo problema com os nomes de URLs, pois ainda está informado o antigo. Como modificar manualmente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade todo o procedimento de migração do Wordpress deve ser minunciosamente pré-meditado para que não tenha problemas tão grande quanto o tamanho do sistema em questão.

Vou mostrar um passo do que deve ser feito e te recomendo começar tudo de novo conforme passo a passo demonstrado apagando todo procedimento feito até agora e começando outra vez para ter certeza de que vai ficar tudo bem.

- Assim que tiver finalizado seu sistema `zip` a pasta da raiz ...
- Exporte o **arquivo zip** até o destino final e `unzip` o arquivo ...
- Acesse o ***wp-config.php*** e coloque as novas informações do bando de dados ...
- Exporte a `DB` em **.sql** ou **.tar.gz** ou qualquer extensão suportada pela importação ...
- Importe esta `DB` para seu banco novo e vá na tabela **wp-options** ...
- Nesta tabela, vai modificar a coluna ***option_name=>siteurl*** ...
- Em ***option_name=>siteurl*** coloque a `url` do domínio definitivo ...

Após ter feito todos estes passos, você deverá acessar **dominiodefinitivo.com.br/wp-admin** e entrar o `nome de usuário` e `senha` na tela de login e assim que abrir a área administrativa deverá imediatamente ir para `Configurações => Geral` e modificar as url's conforme mostrada na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se desenvolveu o site sem mexer nas estruturas do `CMS` e sem ter inserido links manuais no `theme`, ao acessar seu `domínio definitivo` tudo estará ok.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Excelente reposta, atualizei minha pergunta. Estou com erro nas páginas internas agora.

Comment: Você está com problema sério na importação porque `http://www.encamisetados.com.br/` náo vai pro mesmo lugar que `http://encamisetados.com.br/` ... aguardo sua interação.

Comment: Só se eu alterar do "com www" para "sem www".

Comment: Pode tentar mas acho que isso ainda não é a origem do problema. Tenta apagar tudo no domínio definitivo e começar segundo o passo a passo.

Comment: Creio que não é esse o problema, atualizei a minha pergunta, com uma imagem no final de como está.

Comment: Descobri o problema. Era com os links permanentes. Resolvi com esse plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-flush-button/